# How to copy with -t and keep time

Tags: ubuntu, bash, file-transfer

I accidentally removed a file in Ubuntu 16 (Terminal), used photorec to restore it but I've got so many results that I can hardly check manually which is the latest. So I use the command

`find -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 -r grep -lH "Created named pipe" | xargs cp -p -t found/`

to find my .c files in all folders which contain the search string. with cp -t I can copy those files to another place. Unfortunately although I provided `-p (or --preserve=timestamp)` the file date which I see using `ls -alt` is *now* and not the date, that the file I try to copy has. 
I checked the date of the original files I to copy but their date is correct (somewhere in the past)

What can I do to keep the original file date during copy?

Comment: Are you sure photorec can recover the original times for files? It doesn't even recover the original filenames most of the time. Tried Testdisk?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: No, it does not recover them and also not the filenames. The reason is that the metadata like owner, filesize [...] filename and dates are stored in the Inode which is be overwritten with zeros when you delete a file.

Comment: A fair bit of date confusion there, originally I read it as copying the recovered files was changing the date, but it's actually from a 3rd file (or separate date) you want to change the recovered files to match... `touch` can do that, before or after the copying

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution without copying but that is fine because I only want to copy the latest file so this 
`ls -alt $( find -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 -r grep -lH "Created named pipe" )`
does, what I need: The timestamps of all files are printed.

Now I also see that rm a file and restoring it, doesn't restore the edit date. You never stop learning...

Anyway maybe this helps anyone else, cheers.